# Mysql ORDER BY not working when '0' is present

Tags: php, mysql

The following snippet of SQL returns the results that I want for any number of entries until I insert a row with the value `0` for cumulative score. Once I do this I get no results returned. `cumulativescore` is an INT field with no constraints on it.

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("
   select
      cumulativescore
   from 
      reporting
   order by
      cumulativescore asc
");
```

**UPDATE**

I think what's happening is that when I use the following code, `fetchColumn` returns 0 for the first column as it's in ascending order and this breaks my loop. By no results I meant `$arr` was empty but from this example I have learned that that wasn't the best way to test the query. How can I use `fethchColumn` and have `0` values? Or do I need to fetch as an associated array and get the value that way? As a sidenote, what's the most appropriate way to test PDO result sets for values/etc?

```
while($tmp = $stmt->fetchColumn()){
   $arr[] = $tmp;
}
```

Comment: You better post you table structure for a better view.

Comment: No result means error? If so, add the error message please.

Comment: I meant what I said and said what I meant :). No errors, No results.

Comment: are you sure that the table contains any records ? Do you get different  results when you remove 'order by' ?

Comment: Yes, sure of it. Without order by all of the rows are returned except the ones where `cumulative score` is zero.

Comment: Post some sample data or create a fiddle.

Comment: It works for me http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/737e9/2 Problem might be in PHP code.

Comment: See updated question. It WAS the php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while(($tmp = $stmt->fetchColumn()) !== false){
   $arr[] = $tmp;
}
```

three equal signs also check the type of the variable. This is true if the function returns not `false` exactly. If it returns `0` this is `true`.

Comment: Awesome, I don't know how I didn't think of this.